# How to regex today or previous days date using awk and $date?

Tags: date, awk

Column 13 of my data contains date in YYMMDD format. I'm trying to regex using $date for today and previous days. Neither of the following code would work. Could someone give me some insights?

TODAY

```
awk -F, ($13~/$(date '+%Y%m%d')/) {n++} END {print n+0}' file.csv)
```

3 DAYS AGO

```
awk -F, ($13~/$(date -d "$date -3 days" '+%Y%m%d')/) {n++} END {print n+0}' file.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do add samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: as I commented to you on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689709/10971581), consider: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/10971581

Comment: What date command are you using? On OSX -d sets timezone and -v is used for working out time deltas. So `date '+%Y%m%d'` is now and `date -v-72H '+%Y%m%d'` is 3 days (72 hours) earlier.

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. The commands you show are not even syntactically correct. Did you try them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Awk attempts have rather severe quoting problems. You will generally want to single-quote your Awk script, and pass in any parameters as variables with `-v`.

```sh
awk -F, -v when="$(date -d "-3 days" '+%Y%m%d')" '$13~when {n++} END {print n+0}' file.csv
```

Perhaps notice also that `$date` is not defined anywhere. The notation `$(cmd ...)` is a command substitution which runs `cmd ...` and replaces the expression with its output.

Probably also notice that `date -d` is a GNU extension and is not portable, though it will work on Linus and other platforms where you have the GNU utilities installed.

More fundamentally, depending on what's in `$13`, you might want to implement a simple date parsing for that format, so that you can specify a range of acceptable values, rather than search for matches on static text.

This quoting is correct for Bourne-style Unix shells. If you are on Windows, the quoting rules are quite different, and quite likely often impossible to apply in useful ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `AWK` then you might use its' [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) to check if it does work do

```
awk 'END{print strftime("%y%m%d")}' emptyfile.txt
```

which should output current day in `YYMMDD` format. If it does then you might get what you want following way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{today=strftime("%y%m%d");threedago=strftime("%y%m%d",systime()-259200)}END{print today, threedago}' emptyfile.txt
```

output (as of today)

```
210809 210806
```

Explanation: `strftime` first argument is time format `%y` is year 00...99, `%m` is month 01...12, `%d` is day 01...31. Second argument is optional, and it is seconds since start of epoch. If skipped current time is used, `systime()` return number of seconds since start of epoch, `259200` is 72 hours as seconds.

Example of usage as regexp, let say that I have `file.txt` as follows

```
210807 120
210808 150
210809 100
```

and want to retrieve content of 2nd column for today, then I can do

```
awk 'BEGIN{today=strftime("%y%m%d")}$1~today{print $2}' file.txt
```

getting output (as of today)

```
100
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*